# How to refresh my data from parent component?

Tags: angular

Hi I want refresh my timestamp value from parent component.

My parentComponent.ts

```
public updateComponent(){
    this.timestamp = new Date();
    this.timestamp.setDate(this.timestamp.getDate() - 30);
    this.timestamp = this.timestamp.toJSON();
}

public ngOnInit() {
  this.updateComponent();
  interval(10000).subscribe(() => {
      console.error('called');
      console.error(this.timestamp);
      this.updateComponent();
  });

}

//my parent.component.html
<app-dashboard-card [refresh]="timestamp"></app-dashboard-card>



//When I catch my data
private ts: any;

@Input()
set refresh(timestamp: any) {
  console.error("TIMESTAMP CHANGE -> ", timestamp);
  this.ts = timestamp;
};
```

I don't know why my @Input don't catch when timestamp change.

Comment: What's the output in console?

Comment: Only "called" & first timestamp. I haven't "TIMESTAMP CHANGE"

Comment: Is 'called' only logged once? Did you verify that the interval works correctly?

Comment: Is ChangeDetection enabled? Is it corrent timestamp should of type Date OR string?

Comment: I tried your code and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working ***[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muocix?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)*** just using `setInterval()`.

> Suggestion: you can achieve the same without using setter ***[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvhzet?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts);*** simply get your timestamp in your child component as follows -

```
@Input() timestamp: any;

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("TIMESTAMP CHANGE -> ", this.timestamp);
}
```

**Note:** Remember to check console for logs.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnChanges() is called when the reference of object is changed in parent component

```
  import { Input, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['refresh']) {
      //do something after value change
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.